# iOS Compass Heading Change Way

Tags: ios

I am developing an interesting iOS app.
In developing that, I encountered the problem below.

In iOS, generally, the user's position will be shown by his phone's header's orientation.

But in my app, I want to know his position by his phone's back surface orient.
  That is : **iPhone's Z axis**

That is...

1. User Take iPhone with Standing.
2. When he will round with his iPhone by standing, then his compass will be change.
3. I get it and use in programming.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: The compass only works with iphone flat.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, elea. Please read the [faq] before asking question. Also, note that this is not a forum and doesn't work like one.

Comment: Thanks and sorry dandan78...I just know...

Comment: Hi, Rob....then...Is there any good alternative?

Answer (score 2):

See Apple's [Teslameter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Teslameter/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code: "This application implements a Teslameter, a magnetic field detector. It displays the raw x, y, and z magnetometer values, a plotted history of those values, and a computed magnitude (size or strength) of the magnetic field."

Comment: Here's the API reference for that: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLHeading_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks, LPG and Douglas....but...It seems not properly answer for my question, I already know...that...sorry.